getting the list of values shown in the currently displayed v-data-table page
I'm using a v-data-table in vuejs2 with multiple pages of users in my project, showing their info a in set of columns (25 users are shown per page, with a total of 60 000+ users). I'd like to get the list of the users of the page that we're currently on, even after sorting the values through one of the columns. Does v-data-table offer something to get this for you, or do you have to manually calculate it with the sorting and everything?

I have found out how. Using the @current-items event to handle whenever the current list is changed will give you the currently displayed page. Usage example:
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  :items-per-page="25"
  :server-items-length="totalUsers"
  @current-items="handleCurrentItems">

.
.
.
handleCurrentItems(items) {
  // This method will be called whenever the current displayed items change
  // You can perform any operations with the current items here
  console.log("Current Items:", items);
}


Note: This doesn't seem to be available for v-data-table-virtual and also only shows the items of the current page so is still pretty limited in its use.
